# List of users of chat room in firestore how to do that?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My webapp will have chat rooms, i need to implement list of users in that chat rooms.

1. What is the best way to do that? By subcollection or array?

If array:
How to update just one field in document? ( How to add user.uid to array )

If subcollection:
How to get acces to subcolection in v9 firestore?

Code for creating room:

```
await addDoc(collection(db, "rooms"), {
            creator_uid: uid,
            name: _name,
            secured: is_secured,
            password: pass,
            room_members: [],
        });
```

Comment: Without knowing how you will query this data or place limits on it, there's no way of knowing what's best or even what's workable.  Data modeling in NoSQL databases must follow from an understanding of the expected usage of that data.

Comment: For your just [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74114837/what-is-most-optimal-algorithm-for-finding-shortest-path-between-nodes-in-weight), utilize [`networkx.dijkstra_path`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.shortest_paths.weighted.dijkstra_path.html)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the official documentation the best practice would be using subcollections will work better if you have simple, fixed lists of data that you want to keep within your documents, this is easy to set up and streamlines your data structure.  Here is a great google documentation that could help you with the [subcollection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model).